# Spark metrics to graphite

Tags: apache-spark, metrics, graphite

Tell me, is it possible to filter metrics ?

With the included values:
`"spark.metrics.conf. *. source.jvm.class" = org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource"`
a lot of garbage is put in.

How can I filter out what I need ?